# How can I vectorize this piece of code for loading cross-validation from file?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, cross-validation

So I am supposed to load the cross-validation folds from a file (10 iterations, each is 10-folds, so a total of 100, stored sequentially in a 1-dimensional array). Here is the file: https://www.mediafire.com/?bvs0n0eu7gs0if4 . The problem is my code uses for loops intensively and I would like to vectorise it, here is my code:

```
input_filename = 'cv_yeast.mat';
cv = load(input_filename);
nfolds= 10;
niters = 10;

for loop =1:niters   

      for i = 1 : nfolds     
          teIdx = cv.cv{((loop-1)*nfolds + i)};        
          trIdx = [];        
          for j = 1 : nfolds
              if j ~= i                
                  trIdx = [trIdx; cv.cv{(loop - 1)*nfolds + j}];
              end
          end 
          % Processing goes here
   end
  end
```

For some reasons I don't want to vectorise the 2 outer for loops, just the inner one. Can anyone help me, thank you very much :)

Comment: Can one vectorize outer loops? Are there special outer loop registers?

Comment: No you can't, because the real code that I'm working on is at the % processing goes here part, which i believe cannot be easily vectorised

Comment: You usually need a SoA layout to easily vectorize, and a AoS is often  easier conceptually. You could make a vector for that if you do a lot of work on it over and over, otherwise it requires gathers and scatters. So basically there is one and only one vector register and it should ideally be operating on uniform, linear data... Which is almost always the inner loop. It looks like the trIDX[] is trying to do that. And @rahnema1 with the vertcat.

Answer (score 1):

You can create vector of `j` s and concatenate elements of `cv` vertically:

```
for loop =1:niters   
    for i = 1 : nfolds     
        teIdx = cv.cv{((loop-1)*nfolds + i)};        
        J = [1:i-1, i+1:nfolds];
        trIdx = vertcat(cv.cv{(loop - 1)*nfolds + J});
    end
end
```